# Show/Hide div onclick on its specific own anchor

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following HTML generated by PHP:

```
<input><label><a href="#" class="show_hide 139">anchor 139</a></label>
<div class="slidingDiv 139" style="display: none;">content 139</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide 140">anchor 140</a></label>
<div class="slidingDiv 140" style="display: none;">content 140</div>

<input><label><a href="#" class="show_hide 141">anchor 141</a></label>
<div class="slidingDiv 141" style="display: none;">content 141</div>

<input><label><a href="#" class="show_hide 142">anchor 142</a></label>
<div class="slidingDiv 142" style="display: none;">content 142</div>
```

As you can see it, the second class of anchor and div is the same for each iteration of the loop. I did like this because I am using a jquery snippet to hide/show div onclick on anchor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem of this jquery code: It doesn't take into consideration the second class I am adding (to anchor and div). In fact I want to hide the specific div related to his anchor, not all the divs.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Show us the generated  HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: @Steve thank you for your feedback to my issue. Give me one minute

Comment: You will most likely need `$(this).` to refer to the item that you clicked on. What's the full output of `HTML` from the `PHP loop`?

Comment: I edited using the generated HTML, I took some time because I have many other nested items (inputs, labels, spans...). Thank you very much for your remark and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.next` which seems to do the trick for your markup.

```
$(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
```

**Full Code:**

```
<style>
    .slidingDiv { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show_hide').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
          $(this).parent().next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
      });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** I added `display:none` style rule to `.slidingDiv` so that it is hidden when the page is rendering and not after page is rendered.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Thank you for your time. I think I need to provide with generated HTML, I feel I dont need to adress the next item in list but the next class.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces This should work for the markup you had provided.. if not.. try `$(this).next().slideToggle()`.

Comment: one question: next, according its definition gets the immediately following item. Me I have anchor nested in label before the corresponding div. That's whay I added IDs. I hope I am not wrong

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces `.next` gets the next element in your markup, which is the `div` and not the text.

Comment: I understand you but me I have label tag, not a text. Look at my edit.

Comment: If the `<a>` tag is wrapped inside a `label` then use `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle()`. If you couldn't traverse, that is when you should look for a way to link the `<a>` and `div` tag using a data attribute.

Comment: It is working, Thank you for all this knowledge. One last question please, onlcick on anchor, the page goes to the end top,How to make it stay at its position? should I ask this as separate question?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Try using `e.preventDefault()` inside the handler function to stop the default behavior inside the handler. In your case, link tag scrolling all the way up. It scrolls up because you have `href="#"` in the link tag. **Code:** `$('.show_hide').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault()...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Your code:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

was sliding all the div with class `slidingDiv`. But we need to take into consideration the div next to the element being clicked in the current scope only using the `next()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Thank you for your time. I think I need to provide with generated HTML, I feel I dont need to adress the next item in list but the next class.

Comment: I edited using the generated HTML, It took some time because I have many other nested items (inputs, labels, spans...). Thank you very much for your remark and time.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the main idea behind the solution to my problem, except that I was needing parent() because I have anchor nested in label tag.